# variable values to store a array

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I variable values to store a array?

Look my code:

```js
var collection =normal,user,student ;
var array = [collection];
alert(array[0]);
```

In this case, alert would popup a normal,user,student. but i need an array such as array[0] get normal,array[1] get user,array[2] get student like that 
how it is possible

Is there any chance to convert such variable into a JS array?

Comment: Is `normal,user,student` variables?

Comment: @SHERINAS : single string?

Comment: look at the [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) about arrays

Comment: yes.....it is single variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var collection = "normal,user,student";
var jsarray = collection.split(",");
alert(jsarray[0]);
alert(jsarray[1]);
alert(jsarray[2]);
```

Answer (score 3):

As `normal,user,student` are values. You can use `split()` to split the string using `,` as deliminator then indexes can be used to access elements.

```js
var collection = "normal,user,student";
var array = collection.split(',');
console.log(array[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many, many ways to create arrays ... some examples:

```js
// just declare an array directly
var array1 = ["normal", "user", "student"];
console.log(array1[0]);

// use split to create an array out of a string
var collection = "normal,user,student";
var array2 = collection.split(",");
console.log(array2[1]);

// use split and map to create an array by your needs
var collection = " normal, user ,  student  ";
var array3 = collection.split(",").map(function(value) {
    return value.trim();
});
console.log(array3[2]);

// push each value to the array
var array4 = [];
array4.push("normal");
array4.push("user");
array4.push("student");
console.log(array4[0]);

// ...
```

Comment: What do you mean? @SHERINAS

Comment: You're welcome, @SHERINAS! But why do you marked it as success first and now removed it again?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add the existing variables to the array? If so you are just missing your square brackets:

```
var collection = [normal, user, student];
```

If you would like the elements to contain the string values, you would do it like this:

```
var collection = ["normal", "user", "student"];
```